# How to use foreachPartition in Spark 2.2 to avoid Task Serialization error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have the following working code that uses Structured Streaming (Spark 2.2) in order to read data from Kafka (0.10).
The only issue that I cannot solve is related to `Task serialization problem` when using `kafkaProducer` inside `ForeachWriter`.
In my old version of this code developed for Spark 1.6 I was using `foreachPartition` and I was defining `kafkaProducer` for each partition to avoid Task Serialization problem.
How can I do it in Spark 2.2?

```
val df: Dataset[String] = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "test") 
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "true")
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)] 
      .map(_._2)

var mySet = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(Map(
  "metadataBrokerList"->metadataBrokerList,
  "outputKafkaTopic"->outputKafkaTopic,
  "batchSize"->batchSize,
  "lingerMS"->lingerMS))

val kafkaProducer = Utils.createProducer(mySet.value("metadataBrokerList"),
                                mySet.value("batchSize"),
                                mySet.value("lingerMS"))

val writer = new ForeachWriter[String] {

    override def process(row: String): Unit = {
         // val result = ...
         val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](mySet.value("outputKafkaTopic"), "1", result);
        kafkaProducer.send(record)
    }

    override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}

    override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
      true
    }
}

val query = df
        .writeStream
        .foreach(writer)
        .start

query.awaitTermination()

spark.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write implementation of ForeachWriter and than use it. (Avoid anonymous classes with not serializable objects - in your case its ProducerRecord)
Example: `val writer = new YourForeachWriter[String]`
Also here is helpful article about Spark Serialization problems: https://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/demystifying-spark-serialisation-error

Comment: Should `YourForeachWriter` extend `ForeachWriter` and also be serializable?

Comment: No, if parent class has serializable behavior then by default child class also will have serializable behavior. 
You have exception because you use ProducerRecord (not serializable) in your anonymous class and Spark driver can't serialize it and transfer to executor. If you will use instance of your own class this exception will not be present.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand how to follow your recommendation. Should I create a `case class YourForeachWriter(s:String) extends ForeachWriter` and then move the content of `process` to this case class? If so, how can I pass `spark`, `logger` and other variables to this case class?

Comment: Ok, but how should I implement `YourForeachWriter`? What should it contain?

Comment: I understand the reason of the problem and I understand your approach. What I miss is the content of `YourForechWriterClass`. I really do not get the point what should I implement there.

Comment: 1) create new class YourForeachWriterClass extends ForeachWriter
2) move to this class code from your anonymous class
override def process(row: String): Unit = {
         // val result = ...
         val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](mySet.value("outputKafkaTopic"), "1", result);
        kafkaProducer.send(record)
    }

    override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}

    override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
      true
    }
3) Instead of val writer = new ForeachWriter[String] { use val writer = new YourForeachWriterClass

Comment: The problem is that I use `spark` and `myset` inside `process`. How can I pass these parameters?

Comment: Everything must work if you will use your implementation instead of anonymous class. In this case driver will serialize ProducerRecord.
Please, write about the results of your work.

Comment: I get the error Cannot resolve foreach with such signature: `val query = df
            .writeStream
            .foreach(writer)
            .start`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161305/discussion-between-markus-and-yehor-krivokon).

Comment: I tried your solution and got Task Serialization error again. I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837859/task-serialization-error-when-extending-foreachwriter-class